# Where is WPF setting GridViewRowPresenter.Columns for GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

I'm recently exploring a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms771523%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) of using the `GridViewRowPresenter` inside a `TreeView` to make it like a "treegrid". To do this one generally need to define a `GridViewColumnCollection`, and set it to `GridViewRowPresenter.Columns` explicitly. The sample works for me very well.

However since `GridViewRowPresenter` is most often used with `ListView` and `GridView`. I begin to wonder how does the `ListView` and `GridView` setting the Columns property for each row. The xaml most likely like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Length" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListViewItem>Hello</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>World</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Note that though the `GridViewColumnCollection` is defined explicitly, it's not set anywhere for the `ListViewItem`. Eventually each `ListViewItem` will contain a `GridViewRowPresenter`, but in no where the Columns property is set. I checked the open source code for `ListView.cs`, `ListView.xaml`, `ListViewItem.cs`, `ListViewItem.xaml`, `GridViewRowPresenter.cs` `GridViewRowPresenterBase.cs`, in none of these the Columns property is set.

The closest thing I found is `GridView.ColumnCollection` property, I suspect it played some role in connecting the `GridViewRowPresenter.Columns` and `GridView.Columns`, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView.ColumnCollection is the thing you seem to be looking for.

GridViewRowPresenter holds the same instance of ColumnCollection and once arranging its cells it runs through the list of columns for additional information such as desired width or desired DisplayMemberBinding.

There is also a GridViewHeaderPresenter and it does the same as RowPresenter just instead of creating cells per line it creates headers.

**Edit:**

You can see once you reflector the code following statement.

```
protected internal override void PrepareItem(ListViewItem item)
{
    base.PrepareItem(item);

    // attach GridViewColumnCollection to ListViewItem.
    SetColumnCollection(item, _columns);
}
```

That is how GridViewColumnCollection is being passed/attached to ListViewItem.

Its internal as you can see.

Comment: I looked at the default style of ListView and there is something like this <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Margin="2,0,2,0" Columns="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ... It explicitly set the Columns property of GridViewHeaderRowPresenter and there is no magic here. What confused me is that I can't find anywhere a set operation for the GridViewRowPresenter.Columns, how is the GridView.ColumnCollection connected to the Columns property?

Comment: "I looked at the default style of ListView and there is something like this <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Margin="2,0,2,0" Columns="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" .." - well.. that is what I told you in my answer :) I am not sure how you mean your latest question. The Columns property is of type ColumnsCollection that is how they are connected. ColumnsCollection is an ObservableCollection<GridViewColumn> collection.

Comment: Well my question is, what's the corresponding setting statement for the GridViewRowPresenter? We only found the setting for the "header" one not the "row" one, right?

Comment: What? Have you tried googling it? GridViewRowPresenter also has Columns property. For example: <GridViewRowPresenter Columns="{StaticResource gvcc}" /> Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752313(v=vs.110).aspx What do you mean with corresponding setting statement?

Comment: If you use the GridViewRowPresenter yourself, yes you need to set the Columns property manually. What I'm asking is how is WPF doing this by default for ListView-GirdView. If I use the code in my original question. You won't be able to find a setter for columns property anywhere. Not in source code or any styles being applied. I'm not asking how the control should be used, I'm trying to figure out how is WPF itself doing it by default

Comment: Ahhh you mean that. It happens in code and not in XAML. Take a look at my edit in the answer.

Comment: Great, I didn't notice that part.

Answer (score 0):

I will show how to probe into the `GridViewColumn` and `GridViewRowPresenter` interactions at runtime. Consider the following simplified **XAML**:

```
<ListView x:Class="demo_listview"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wd="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Documents;assembly=PresentationFramework"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">

    <!-- ... -->

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>

            <!-- ... -->

            <GridViewColumn x:Name="my_gv_column" Width="100">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="my_textblock" Text="ABCD" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <!-- ... -->

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Now in code, override a method such as `ListView.ClearContainerForItemOverride` as shown below. The code will modify the background color of the `TextBlock` to make it red:

[image]

Note that the red color persists after "Clearing" due to containers being recycled. I picked that function to keep the demo simple, since it ensures that the templates will be fully instantiated for examination. Otherwise, for example, if you get 'null' for `gv_row`, for example, you need to call `lvi.ApplyTemplate()` immediately prior.

I assume you are able to get the `ListViewItem` easily enough for the row you're interested in. So from any fully-instantiated `ListViewItem` at runtime, we can now see how to get to the contents of a particular instantiated `CellTemplate` at runtime. Additional remarks follow below the code.

```
public partial class demo_listview : ListView
{
    protected override void ClearContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject el, object item)
    {
        base.ClearContainerForItemOverride(el, item);

        var lvi = (ListViewItem)el;

        var gv_row = (GridViewRowPresenter)lvi.Template.FindName("5_T", lvi);

        var ix = ((GridView)View).Columns.IndexOf(my_gv_column);
        var cp = (ContentPresenter)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(gv_row, ix);

        var tb = (TextBlock)my_gv_column.CellTemplate.FindName("my_textblock", cp);
        tb.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
};
```

The first step is to get the `GridViewRowPresenter` from the `ListViewItem`. There are a few ways to do this. Above, I use the magic constant "5_T" to get the instantiation from the template name. This constant is as defined by **WPF**, so it will work as long as you are using the standard `ListViewItem` its built-in control template.

Next we need the index of the column we're interested in. The column instance itself is easily accessed in **C#** by giving it a name (`my_gv_column`) in the **XAML**. As for its index, I'm not sure if the `IndexOf` technique shown here will continue to work if columns are reordered. If not, the correct result would be obtained by fetching, via reflection, the value of the private `_actualIndex` field (or `ActualIndex` property) from the `GridViewColumn` of interest.

Next, using `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild`, get the visual child of the `GridViewRowPresenter` which corresponds to the desired column index; this will be the `ContentPresenter` for the cell! With this, you can do another `FindName` search within the template to find the actual instantiated control you're looking for, by name. In the example, we successfully get the `TextBlock` instance and then change its background color to demonstrate the result.

Answer (score 0):

It's done in FrameworkElementFactory.ApplyAutoAliasRules:

```
            // GridViewRowPresenter auto-aliases Content and Columns to Content
            // property GridView.ColumnCollection property on the templated parent.
```

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/FrameworkElementFactory.cs,9ce27c5244be816c,references

So, `GridViewRowPresenter.Columns` defaults to `{TemplateBinding GridView.ColumnCollection}`.